# Can a dog contract the Ebola virus?

Tags: dogs, diseases

Can a dog contract the Ebola virus? I heard that monkeys and/or rodents can give you Ebola if they have it, but I am just curious as if a dog can contract it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Canine Corner: Can Dogs Get Infected by the Ebola Virus?](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/canine-corner/201409/can-dogs-get-infected-the-ebola-virus)

This link, I think, provides the best answer with scientific evidence and provided myself with the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately, we have more to worry about now since Ebola is actually in the US.

Here is a piece of the article that directly answers that question by Dr. Coren:

> "Although dogs are susceptible to Ebola, the CDC concluded that "infected dogs are asymptomatic", meaning that they do not develop symptoms. During the early phase of their infection, however, they can spread the disease to humans and other animals through licking, biting, urine, and feces. However, the good news is that once the virus is cleared from the dog it is no longer contagious. Dogs do not die from Ebola infections."

Answer (score 7):

According to researchers, dogs, pigs, many other mammals, and birds are susceptible to ebola.  The current epidemic is believed to have originated in bats and jumped to people hunting bats for food.

In dogs, the virus is often asymptomatic; Meaning they won't show symptoms of the virus.

source: Weingartl HM, Nfon C, Kobinger G (2013). "Review of Ebola virus infections in domestic animals". Dev Biol (Basel) 135: 211–8.
[web abstract](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23689899)

Comment: Fun fact, the fruit bats that commonly carry ebola are also asymptomatic. Which is why it's so difficult to find out what colonies have the virus without performing expensive blood analysis.

Comment: Animal transmission sounds worse than human transmission, because if jumps to America and ends up dormant in animal populations, it could flare up years later just like it does in Africa.

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS - Except that the primary source of transmission is through consumption of tainted meat.  If it ends up in the bat population, then gets transmitted to the deer population the US could see a serious recurring outbreaks that would be a problem though.